# Kentico 9 having memory leak and then proceeds by having high CPU

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, kentico

We have  strange problem after upgrading our Kentico 8 to Kentico 9.0.28.
Our servers got 64GB RAM, 2x8core CPU. 
After upgrade we notice the memory slowly going up by w3wp process tied to the Kentico 9 site.
After roughly 30min, the CPU starts to spike up and down 90% - 50%.
Recycling the application pool helps but needs to be done as frequent as every 30 mins
We plan to upgrade to 9.0.50 to see if this helps to fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify what your question is and what you have you done to resolve the problem you are facing (attach logs, debug information, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the hotfix 50 will resolve your issue.  The memory leak issue was resolved in v9 hotfix 31.

Comment: Yup, we just applied hotfix50, it does help a bit but I can't tell 100% is fixed as the memory still increase. We are recycling the application pool periodically to avoid the issue.

Comment: Kentico support asked to disable this 1. Go to Settings > Security & Membership > On-line users > Monitor on-line users 
2. Restart the IIS application pool  - not sure how it will help but will try and see.

Comment: If you don't have an EMS license then unchecking that option won't make a difference.